# Authentication between Salesforce and another website

Tags: authentication

i have a question regarding mutual authentication between Salesforce and another website.

My client currently using Salesforce Communities for its customers. He also has a website for different purpose but for the sames clients.

To avoid two authentications when switching from Salesforce to the website and vice versa, we would like to add a link in both site which manage autologin.

The common key is the email but we don't want to use password because they are differents in the two site.
Is-there a way to login to Salesforce with something else than the password ?

I thought i could create a webservice accepting an email address and a certificate, which make an autologin, returning a sessionid allowing the other website to login to salesforce. But it seems not possible.
So oath ? Mutual authentication ? Apex class ? Another thing ?
I'm a little confused about the solution ...

Thanks !

Comment: You'll want to use OAuth2 or SAML as your authentication method. Neither require knowledge of a password, but instead use tokens and assertions (respectively). The specific method that's right for you depends on whom initiates the login session. SAML lets the external site log the user in to Salesforce, OAuth2 lets the external site get a login from Salesforce. Odds are, SAML is the better choice in this case, but might require more work than you're willing to put forth.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will investigate in that way :)